# Should we fixed up closed questions?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

Sometimes when doing mass retagging, closed questions get into the mix.

Along with the retagging, I often also fix up the question.

Now should I also fix up the closed questions, or don't we really care about them?

(retagging them seems to make sense as, for example, when burninating a tag, the tag will remain if it's on a closed question)

Comment: Depends how much they can be fixed up; if its to "acceptable question" then awesome

Comment: And if you think it's not possible for it to be fixed up into something acceptable then voting to delete it would be how you "handle" such a question.

Comment: Depends. If the question has no answers or votes then it's likely to be autodeleted in a few days anyway, so you'd be wasting your time for those.

Comment: @JonW It's often questions that have been closed for a while already, so they won't get auto-deleted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point of closing a question and not deleting it straight-away was to give a chance to the asker (or other people) the chance to improve the question so that it meets what's acceptable on the site. If you follow that spirit, it's a good thing to fix the question as long as the improvement helps make it acceptable (don't just do cosmetic edit). If you clearly can't make an improvement that will make the question re-opened than voting to delete it is the best thing to do.

Comment: What about duplicates? They typically shouldn't be reopened or deleted, to my knowledge. And I guess old off-topic popular closed questions should be improved (without the aim to reopened).

Comment: @Dukeling They won't be reopened or deleted, but there's still value in editing them. People that do Google search often fall on those question and when the question is clear, it helps a lot to see if it's the good thing they are looking for.